# UWP Drag and Drop on Formatted Text

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

In my uwp app, I'm going to ask a user to make a meaningful sentence from bulk of words:

For example, when user opens the app, he/she will see:

"seek stackoverflow place great a is help for"

And after that, user needs to drag and drop each word on a correct position to make a meaningful sentence from given words, which is:

"stackoverflow is a great place to seek for help"

Also please keep in mind that, text should be **aligned center**.

With single line sentences this can be done by horizontal listview. I've already done that. For multiple lines I used gridview. I make every string in text as a listview/gridview item and use reorder property of listview/gridview controls to make this work.

But at that point i have a problem.

2 lined text should be look like this:

```
------------------
      -------
```

But at the moment it looks like this:

```
-----------------
---------
```

I know this is because gridview. But I have no idea at the moment to overcome this problem. Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

**.xaml:**

```
<StackPanel 
        x:Name="stack_panel1" 
        Margin="50" 
        Orientation="Vertical"
        Background="AliceBlue"
        Padding="50"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        >

        <GridView x:Name="GridView1"
                  AllowDrop="True"
                  CanDragItems="True"
                  CanReorderItems="True"
                  Background="PaleGoldenrod"
                  Width="500"
                  Height="500">
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="5"></ItemsWrapGrid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        </GridView>

    </StackPanel>
```

**.cs:**

```
public sealed partial class DragDropDemo : Page
    {
        ObservableCollection<string> collection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        public DragDropDemo()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            collection.Add("seek");
            collection.Add("stackoverflow");
            collection.Add("place");
            collection.Add("great");
            collection.Add("a");
            collection.Add("is");
            collection.Add("help");
            collection.Add("for");

            GridView1.ItemsSource = collection;

        }

    }
```

Note: By saying "text should be aligned center" I didn't mean centering one item in one cell:

For instance:

Assume we have a gridview with max column count for each row is 5 and our sentence is again:

"stackoverflow is a great place to seek for help"

At the moment it is seen like that:

```
stackoverflow is a great place
to seek for help
```

But instead I want it to be look like this:

```
stackoverflow is a great place
      to seek for help
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not saw your xaml code, but I made a simple code sample to show you how to make the multiple line text aligned center.

```
<GridView>
        <GridViewItem Width="300">
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords">Also please keep in mind that, text should be aligned center.</TextBlock>
        </GridViewItem>
</GridView>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Xavier Xie. Forget to add details sorry for that. By saying "center alignment" i didn't want to mean center an item in one cell. For details please check my edited question.

Comment: @GencerTUTU If you have to use `ItemsWrapGrid`, it's impossible. Because the `ItemsWrapGrid` control is designed to position child elements sequentially from left to right or top to bottom in an ItemsControl.

Comment: To achieve your target, you need to make a custom panel for your special requirement. You could check the [UWP Community Toolkit/WrapPanel](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/WrapPanel/WrapPanel.cs) source code to learn how to make such a custom panel.